# Disable usb mass storage

Tags: usb, security, mass-storage

I want to disable usb mass storage on Ubuntu desktop 10.04, 11.04 and 11.10.

As security policy to avoid data leakage. But in case of emergency there easy way getting usb mass storage back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Blacklist the `usb_storage` module by adding `blacklist usb_storage` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

To load the module manually, run `sudo modprobe usb_storage`.

Answer (score -2):

Just rename `storage` to `storage-old`:

mv /lib/modules/3.2.0-35-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/usb/storage /lib/modules/3.2.0-35-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/usb/storage-old

You must do so when the kernel version updated

Comment: This  would stop working when installing kernel updates would install a new kernel with this module again

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to do modifications to files within /usr or /lib for reasons like this.  Always better to modify conf files in /etc where possible.

Answer (score -2):

just rename storage to storage-old:

for me renaming as /lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/storage-old

just didn't work , but when i created tar archive named storage-old.tar and deleted storage-old the method seems to work